# iOS How should I open phonebook through coding

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, abaddressbook, abaddressbooksource

I am doing one project in that I am sending messages to multiple user.
When I am composing message I took one `textfield` for enter contact. **When I click on contact `textfield` I want to open phone contact** (like In Phone default compose message view how the all contacts appears when user click on **"To"**) `view`.

In `Android` development we can open the phone contacts bye using **"contact intent"** I want to create like the same.

By using **ABAddressBook** I am able to fetch all contacts. But I dont want to create custom  phonebook contact. So please help me that is there any default method to get default phone contacts controller in iOS.

For example how we directly open the setting page by using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

this . I want the something like this to open the phone contact and once i finished any action(i.e selected any contact number) then it will get back to my app

Comment: Have you tried the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1